# 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to StackOverflow and programming in general, so sorry in advance if I am not explaining things correctly.

I am getting the error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

This occurs when the following code gets to `window.Show()`

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        myApp.Common.AppInfo.Local = "en-GB";

        SoftwareMaintenance.Seed();

        myApp5Db.Init(typeof(myAppDb_SQL2008));
        myAppDb.Init();

        if (myAppDb.IsValid)
        {
            Node.LoadTree(Node.ROOT); //loading the first level only
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DefaultTraceListener traceListener = new DefaultTraceListener();

        PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(traceListener);
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Error;


        base.OnStartup(e);


        if (true)
        {
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            window.Show();
        }

    }
```

Now I've done a lot of research across the net and everything points to a loop being stuck. In my case I don't think this is the case, as another developers machine can run the code fine.

This other computer is exactly the same (HP EliteBook 8670p) except it has more RAM. My one 8GB's, the other 16GB's [could this be the cause?]

Software-wise both running Windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio 2013. The SQL Server's on each machine differ, my machine running SQL Server 2012 Developers Edition, the other SQL Server 2008 Standard.

```
// The Call Stack after window.Show()

[Managed to Native Transition]

// First 3 Call Stack's showed once 

WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.GetKeyboardLayout(int dwLayout)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.TextServicesManager.PostProcessInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs e)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)

// The next 9 lines are repeated over 20+ times

PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(System.Windows.DependencyObject newFocus, System.Windows.Input.IKeyboardInputProvider keyboardInputProvider, bool askOld, bool askNew, bool forceToNullIfFailed)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.DependencyObject focus, bool askOld, bool askNew, bool forceToNullIfFailed)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.IInputElement element)
InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Interactions.XamDialogWindow.v14.1.dll!Infragistics.Controls.Interactions.XamDialogWindow.DialogManager.XamDialogWindow_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)
```

Comment: I just want add that this a WPF project, on .NET 4.5

Comment: What method is that `window.Show();` in? From the fragment above, it looks like it's outside of any method.

Comment: You need to show what method that `if(true)` block is in. Also, a copy of the stack trace from the exception should be helpful

Comment: @phoog I didn't vote to close, but this question has some issues providing context about the error.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflowException results not when a loop is stuck, but when a method calls itself too many times.  This is called recursion.  It can also be caused by mutual recursion, in which two or more methods call each other in repeated succession.

This could be happening if the code fragment that uses the `new` operator to create a new `MainWindow` instance is called by one of the methods called in the MainWindow constructor, or by any method called in one of those methods.  I would suspect one of these lines:

```
myApp5Db.Init(typeof(myAppDb_SQL2008));
myAppDb.Init();
```

But other lines could be the culprit.

If you post your application's `Main` method, it might offer some clues, as would the code of the methods called by the MainWindow constructor, and the full method in which your `while (true)` loop is defined.

Another idea: if you check the call stack in the debugger, at the point where the exception is thrown, you ought to find out pretty quickly where the recursion is taking place.

Comment: Thank you phoog, I have provided the method. And will run over the call stack in debugger

Comment: This is the only Call Stack in the list at the breakpoint of window.Show()

> myApp.View.exe!myApp.View.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) Line 137 C#

After the window.Show() is called, the error appears and the 'Call stack with external code' has a number of lines that appear to repeat.. I will post them in another comment in hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I have added the Call Stack from after the window.Show() line

Answer (score 0):

> // The next 9 lines are repeated over 20+ times
>
> PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(System.Windows.DependencyObject
>   newFocus, System.Windows.Input.IKeyboardInputProvider
>   keyboardInputProvider, bool askOld, bool askNew, bool
>   forceToNullIfFailed)
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.DependencyObject
>   focus, bool askOld, bool askNew, bool forceToNullIfFailed)
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.IInputElement
>   element)
>   InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Interactions.XamDialogWindow.v14.1.dll!Infragistics.Controls.Interactions.XamDialogWindow.DialogManager.XamDialogWindow_LostKeyboardFocus(object
>   sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate
>   handler, object target)
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject
>   sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject
>   sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs
>   args)

**If I were to guess I'd say you must have a Key Event that gets triggered on every node of the TreeView/Node**, focus in on the code in the `XamDialogWindow_LostKeyboardFocus` event...